# non breaking spaces , breakes while Div page

Tags: html, css

Here is simple versioun of my html

```
<div class="container">
  <aside>...</aside>
  <div class="wrapp">
  .....
 <p>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;consectetur,&nbsp;adipisicing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Non&nbsp;dolores&nbsp;ad&nbsp;et&nbsp;v ....</p>
</div>
```

This `&nbsp;` breakes whole my html as `.container` has `max-width 1000px;` `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and `word-wrap: break-word;` not helping solve this issue , it only makes paragraph go to new line. [without non-breaking space](https://prnt.sc/10cn1ly) ,  [with non-breaking spaces which breakes the page](https://prnt.sc/10cn27c)

Comment: max-width of wrap helped to solve this issue , cant belive that solution was so simple

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried white-space: nowrap

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp